# How will the implementation of Kovri work from a user perspective?

Tags: full-node, kovri, i2p

This is really a multi-part question that I'm happy to trim/change/delete if it's too broad and/or speculative.

Part A - Assuming an average, not-particularly-tech-savvy user is excited about Kovri implementation, what can they expect when it is rolled out?  That is, can they expect to double-click on an installation file they ordinarily would (an installation file that includes the daemon, the wallet, probably the GUI wallet by that time, and Kovri), and the installation/setup will just ask clearnet/i2p/both?  And then, once it's set up, the node just runs like usual, and they won't need to increase their technical prowess to make it work or maintain it?

Part B - For the more experienced user who wants to route their internet traffic in such a way that they can browse eep sites, will selecting "i2p" in the installation/setup allow for routing any i2p traffic (not just monero), as though they had set up a dedicated i2p relay?

Part C - Will the i2p relay be able to filter the traffic to only pass through monero-related traffic, or is i2p implementation more of an off/on switch?

Comment: I wonder the same as your part A, and I hope I2P will be so integrated and activated *by default* that people won't even know that there is an option not to use it. This is the way it should be with all privacy enhancements IMHO, the same way nowadays Monero requires a minimum mixin level for all transactions and will eventually enforce that they all be RingCT transactions too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> what can they expect when it is rolled out?

The Kovri router will be baked in to the Monero code, so all a user will need to do is select an option indicating whether they want to use the Kovri routing feature or not. I think its still up in the air whether it will be on by default or not. I think it will be on by default.

> as though they had set up a dedicated i2p relay?

Yes, I believe that is the idea. In addition to routing the Monero transaction traffic, the Kovri router will also provide a gateway into i2p and will serve to support the i2p network.

> Will the i2p relay be able to filter the traffic to only pass through monero-related traffic

This will probably be an option, considering that running a full i2p router can use lots of bandwidth per month. This is similar to how a user can throttle their Monerod with a download and upload rate cap.