# Looking for an easy explanation about kovri

Tags: blockchain, kovri

I still don't get what kovri actually is.

Can anyone provide an easy explanation?

I looked at YouTube for videos, but couldn't find any. Also other links didn't help.

Does anyone know a picture which explains it easily?

I don't know if I want to donate to this project because I really don't understand the benefit.

Answer (score 13):

From the project's FAQ:

> ### What is Kovri?
>
> Kovri is a secure, private, untraceable C++ router implementation of
>   the [I2P](https://geti2p.net) anonymous network. What was once a fork
>   of i2pd, Kovri has become a unique, actively-developed,
>   community-driven C++ I2P implementation with many improvements,
>   security enhancements, and new features over its predecessor.

[Frequently Asked Questions (and answers)](https://github.com/monero-project/kovri/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md)

Comment: It sounds like it might be a separate network from I2P, since it is referred to as another implementation of it. Is that understanding correct?

Comment: @user141 it uses the same network. The main difference is that Kovri is written in the much more performant and portable C++ whereas i2pd is written in Java, and as explained above it also has some extra features and fixes.

Answer (score 7):

Kovri is a project that will allow the Monero network - or part of it anyway - to be transmitted over I2P.  Perhaps the answer to this question will illuminate you a bit.

[How will the implementation of Kovri work from a user perspective?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1815/how-will-the-implementation-of-kovri-work-from-a-user-perspective)

Answer (score 4):

The normal I2P router (that lets you connect to and use the I2P network) is written in Java. Kovri is a project to create an I2P router in C++ so that it works with Monero.